# Convert longitude/latitude to pixels in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: google-maps, pixel, latitude-longitude

I'm searching for a way to convert longitude/latitude to pixels relative to a Map view. Basically, I'm looking for something similar to Projection.toPixels(), as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection).

What I want to do is the following: I need to add annotations with background images and texts on them, and since such a feature is not possible with the default annotations, I have to somehow calculate their position in the Map view and add labels (as children views), instead.

I've spent almost a week working on it, without any result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property on an annotation to set its image and a title that will displayed when clicked (hover over it). see here:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Map.Annotation-object

Is this not exactly what your looking for?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am aware of that. However, this is not what I'm looking for. I want the text to be displayed on the top of the image and not on user click. Also, there are various other custom features that I want to apply on the map and, this can't be done with the default annotation, for sure.

I have already implemented such an app for android with the method I mentioned earlier (Projection.toPixels()). The thing is I can't find something similar for Titanium.

Comment: seems like a small hack but what about this??

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135862/convert-longitutelatidute-to-pixels

Comment: hehe, this is my own post on the appcelerator forum. As I replied there, I 'll try out the guy's proposal as soon as possible. Afterwards, I'll post a comment (or hopefully a solution) both there and here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way to convert lat/lng to pixels, but I do have a way to get images and text on annotations.  It is kind of a "hackish" way to do it, but it works.  Basically, all you do is create a custom view with whatever you want in it.  After you have your view setup, then for the image property of the annotation, you set it to yourCustomView.toImage().

Here is an example:

```
//Setup device size variables
var deviceWidth = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;
var deviceHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;

//Create a new window
var w = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    width:deviceWidth,
    height:deviceHeight
})

//Create view for annotation
var annotationView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:50,
    height:50,
    backgroundImage:'http://www.insanedonkey.com/images/bubble.png',
})

//Add text to the annotation view
var annotationText = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    width:'auto',
    height:'auto',
    text:'785k',
    font:{fontSize:12,fontWeight:'bold'},
    color:'#fff',
})
annotationView.add(annotationText);

//Create a new annotation
var newAnnotation = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude:36.134513,
    longitude:-80.659690,
    animate:true,
    image:annotationView.toImage() //Convert the annotationView to an image blob
});


var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    region:{latitude:36.134513, longitude:-80.659690, latitudeDelta:0.0009,     longitudeDelta:0.0009},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:[newAnnotation],
    mapType:Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    width:2000,
    height:2000

});

//Add the mapview to the window
w.add(mapview);

//Open the window
w.open();
```

I hope this helps out.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just tested your proposal but it doesn't seem to work. All it does is to show the default red pin instead of the custom view you created. I've only tried it on simulator. Any ideas why this might happens?